# C# real time chart desktop application too slow

Tags: c#, multithreading, charts, serial-port, real-time

I am taking over a **C# code** from someone who implemented a **desktop application** to read real time data from the **Serial Port** and displaying it in charts (using the **Chart Class**).

The code seems to be working, but is *very slow*. It seems to be updating the chart around once in 4 seconds (0.25Hz). However, I can see that it is multi-threaded and has no delay commands, so I don't understand why it is running so slow. Could the updating of charts slow it down? Ideally I would like to achieve **1000 data points per second** (1kHz), displaying it in **real time** and **saving** it to the hard disk, where the size of each data point is about **30 bytes.**

I spent few days understanding the code, but it's too cumbersome to follow, all written in a single file, with no comments. *Is my goal of reading 1000 data points per second realistic/achievable?*

I'm also considering to re-write the code (as opposed to trying to fix it), considering it's only about **2,500 lines** long. Any tips would be appreciated. Also, if I rewrite the code, *what language might be better for this application*?

Comment: are you serious? 30Bytes*1000data/sec using serial port? no , not realistic at all! you can re-write the code if you want but you have to consider your specifications again, can you tell me what is your baudrate?

Comment: Is 30 kB/s really that much? At the moment the baudrate is 38400. But it will be increased accordingly. I am not so much worried about the hardware. I wonder if a "regular" computer (i7 3Ghz 8G ram) can keep up with the real time chart display and saving.

Comment: That's 30,000 bytes/s which is 240,000 bits per second. The highest baud rate over a serial port I've seen is 230,400 bits per second, which is just shy of your required throughpout.

Comment: btw what is data type that handles 30bytes? there must be some data processing right?

Comment: How many points are you wanting to show on the chart at one time? If you want to update the plot every second with 1000 (or however many) new points, but remove the oldest 1000 points, that's not a problem. If you keep the old points while adding new ones, eventually your app will choke. Chart rendering becomes very slow when you have 10k or 20k points.

Answer (score 1):

I developed some code where I got significant performance improvement, it may work for you. Here is what I did-

Step 1: I would first identify, which one is the bottle neck, `drawing/rendering of the chart`

**or** `serial port`

Step 2: If you find its the rendering-- then add this in your form/chart setup, it will draw much faster. But first double check to make sure you're not in remote desktop mode.

```
 <!-- language: c# -->

    // No double buffering for remote, only local
    public bool OptimizeOfLocalFormsOnly(System.Windows.Forms.Control chartControlForm)
    {
     if (!System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.TerminalServerSession)
     {
              SetUpDoubleBuffer(chartControlForm);
              return true;
     }
     return false;

    }

    public static void SetUpDoubleBuffer(System.Windows.Forms.Control chartControlForm)
    {

       System.Reflection.PropertyInfo formProp = 
       typeof(System.Windows.Forms.Control).GetProperty("DoubleBuffered",         System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);    
       formProp.SetValue(chartControlForm, true, null); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you using winform application :

Use `serialPort` component :

1. Configure its `properties` : (BaudRate, DataBits, StopBits, Parity ...)
2. Make use of its `event` (DataReceived) to collect your inputs.

You can send commands in a loop and collect the inputs/drawing them on chart component roughly like :

```
while(/*some condition*/)
{
  serialPort.Write(/* your command */);

  // you have to think of response time
  // so implement something that waits a bit before calling the port again
  // I would do it using timers

  int tick= Environment.TickCount;
  while(Environment.TickCount - tick <= 100) // wait 100 milliseconds
  { 
    Application.DoEvents();
  }

}

// collect the data as:
private void serialPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
  // use according to your needs, for example
  string data = "";
  int readByte;
  int available;

  available = serialPort.BytesToRead;
  if(available >= 30) // 30 bytes as stated in your question
  {
    for(int i=0; i<30; i++)
    {
      readByte = serialPort.ReadByte();
      data += String.Format("{0:2X}", readByte);
    }

    // you can call some methods to save/display your collected data from here
    save_to_file(data);
    display_to_chart(data);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I developed a similar app where I was displaying 16charts * 256 samples/sec. Storing the data in a buffer and creating a separate thread for updating the charts worked for me.

When new data is read, data is stored in a list or array. Since it is real-time data, the timestamps are also generated here. Using the sample rate of the data acquired: timeStamp = timeStamp + sampleIdx/sampleRate;

```
public void OnDataRead(object source, EEGEventArgs e)
        {
            if ((e.rawData.Length > 0) && (!_shouldStop))
            {
                lock (_bufferRawData)
                {
                    for (int sampleIdx = 0; sampleIdx < e.rawData.Length; sampleIdx++)
                    {
                        // Append data
                        _bufferRawData.Add(e.rawData[sampleIdx]);

                       // Calculate corresponding timestamp
                      secondsToAdd = (float) sampleIdx/e.sampleRate;

                    // Append corresponding timestamp
                    _bufferXValues.Add( e.timeStamp.AddSeconds(secondsToAdd));
                    }
                }
```

Then, create a thread that sleeps every N ms (100ms is suitable for me for a 2 seconds display of data, but if I wanna display 10 seconds, I need to increase to 500ms of sleep time for the thread)

```
 //Create thread
 //define a thread to add values into chart
 ThreadStart addDataThreadObj = new ThreadStart(AddDataThreadLoop);
 _addDataRunner = new Thread(addDataThreadObj);
 addDataDel += new AddDataDelegate(AddData);

 //Start thread
 _addDataRunner.Start();
```

And finally, update the charts and make the thread sleep every N ms

```
 private void AddDataThreadLoop()
    {
        while (!_shouldStop)
        {
            chChannels[1].Invoke(addDataDel);

            // Sleeep thread for 100ms
            Thread.Sleep(100); 
        }
    }
```

The AddData method, simply reads the X (timestamp) and Y values stored in the buffer and add its to the charts using ptSeries.Points.AddXY(xValue, yValue)